# Check if python code is running as a background task in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I have a Python project which I sometimes run as a background process in Linux. If the process is not running as a background task I want to provide some plots. Is it possible to check from within the Python code to see whether it is running as a background task and surpress the plots?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "background task"? Do you want to check whether a process with a certain name is running at all? Do you want to check whether it is the child process of something else or detached?

Comment: I run the code using: nohup python task.py &. It throws an error when trying to plot if my environment has been logged out. I'm currently manually changing my python code to supress the plots if i'm going to run it in the background. However, it would be convenient if it knows by itself it should plot or not.

Comment: @Boris Mulder I suppose you could pipe the jobs command to the terminal and make a decision based on the result using the subprocess.call() function.

Comment: EAFP: put a suitable try/except around the plotting code.

Comment: @AlexHall That would be a good idea indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with a  python daemon.

You see [this article](https://catalin-festila.blogspot.com/2018/09/fedora-28-start-service-daemon-with.html) for more help.